# Testing SharePoint 2010 Beta

Tags: beta, testing

I have a Virtual Machine with MOSS 2007 (Enterprise), VS2008 and SQL 2005.

I want to start exploring 2010. I need to know what I need to get started.

Can I download 2010 beta from the Microsoft site? Can I just install it without any conflicts with my existing setup?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you start with downloading the ready to run [SharePoint 2010 (beta) Information Worker virtual machine](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0c51819b-3d40-435c-a103-a5481fe0a0d2&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a clean build instead of installing it on your existing server unless you don't have anything important on that server and do not mind clearing it all out.

I would really recommend going the vm route like Wictor mentioned, but the regular installs are available.  This link should get you to them:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee388573.aspx

The link that provided also does a good job of giving you the pre-reqs as well.  As long as you are already running x64 then it shouldn't be a big deal.